# Why is my onbeforeunload handler causing an "Unspecified error" error?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6, onbeforeunload

I am using the following JavaScript function within IE6:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {  
  if (itemChanged) {  
     return 'You have made changes to data on this page.  If you navigate away from this page without first saving your data, the changes will be lost.';  
  }  
};
```

But when I press the Cancel button on the dialog, I am getting a JavaScript page error:

> Error: Unspecified error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your value of (itemChanged). Is it possible something else causes the error? It works fine for me.

[Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/uwudu) sample.

Comment: you're saying that going to the Jsbin page, clicking close and "Cancel" won't result in the "Unspecified error," right? Was that your point?