# IE9 onbeforeunload called twice when window.location changed in button event... minimal reproduction

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-9, onbeforeunload

I've been hammering and hammering at this and just can't get anywhere.

I have a cancel button that does a "window.location = '404.htm';" when clicked. The onbeforeunload handler fires twice, but only if the user clicks "Stay on this page" to the first dialog. A normal navigation (page refresh, going to home page) the onbeforeunload handler only fires once.

I've managed to repro the behavior with a minimal amount of HTML and script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test page</title>
</head>
<body onbeforeunload="return 'Unsaved changes';">
    <form name="form1" id="form1">
        <input id='cmdCancel' type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="window.location = '404.htm';" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /*
         * Connecting the events via code makes no difference
         *
        document.forms[0].cmdCancel.onclick =
            function () {
                alert('Clicked cancel. About to navigate...');
                window.location = '404.htm';
            };

        window.onbeforeunload = function () {
            return "Unsaved changes";
        }; 

        */   
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

There are lots of hits for "onbeforeunload called twice" but no minimal reproduction and no actual solutions.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Try this, this worked for me. This solution was originally posted by Amit at 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/sharepointinfopath/thread/13000cd8-5c50-4260-a0d2-bc404764966d?prof=required

Remember, disabling the onbeforeunload temporarily and enabling it back after a short while is the key.

```
var checkChangesEnabled = true;

window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;

function confirmExit()
{
  if(checkChangesEnabled)
  {
    event.returnValue = "You have not saved your document yet.";
    disableCheck();
  }
}

function disableCheck()
{
  checkChangesEnabled = false;
  setTimeout("enableCheck()", "100");
}

function enableCheck()
{
   checkChangesEnabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As anyways your `onbeforeunload` is interpreted through JS, you probably can use a boolean flag in a global variable to know whether it's the first time the process started by the event runs. Like:

```
<head>
  ...
  <script ...>
  var flag=true;
  var ret="";
  function getoff() {
    if(flag) {
      //do your things and save your return value to the global variable "ret"
      //ret="Unsaved changes";
      flag=false; //with this, the code above will be executed only once
    }
    return ret; //the second call will return the same thing as the first call, as first call's return value is stored in a global variable, and is not modified during the second call
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body onbeforeunload="return getoff();">
...
```

Another possibility perhaps, as according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6917074/1269732) the problem seems to come from changing the page using JS, you can use a hidden hyperlink to change the page using HTML, something like:

```
<a href="404.htm" id="myButton" style="display:none;visibility:hidden;"></a>
```

Then your button could do:

```
<input type="button" ... onclick="document.getElementById('myButton').click();">
```

Assuming any of this works, a hidden link like that is an ugly hack (the first possibility isn't much prettier anyway), but what doesn't require some ugly hacks when it's about having MSIE behave like if it was a web browser...

Comment: The flag approach does not work. If on either the first or second invocation if there is no return value (eg. "return;", "return null;") the navigation takes place. There's no way to cancel the navigation and stay on the page without IE prompting the user (so IE "thinks" both invocations are valid onbeforeunload calls).

Comment: I get this, but the principle of the flag is to set it to false once you're in the if-block of the getoff() function, so that your code inside will be executed only once. Then, the second call to onbeforeunload will just return the same value it returned the first time (as it'll be stored in ret). Anyway, does the second approach works ?

Comment: Just to come back to the flag approach... if you return the same value twice then the user is prompted twice. There really is no way around this using flags. However the hidden A works... except calling .click() does not actually do the navigate (this may be jquery or normal IE behavior). Adding an onclick to the A and having that do "location = '404.htm';" does work when triggered from jquery.

Answer (score 0):

With the next code, you can fix this for any case:

```
window.location = 'javascript:window.location = "http://www.google.com"';
```

Comment: this fix appearing message twice during accept go away, but add twice asking during reject redirect

Answer (score 0):

I found that it is called twice when using postback and non-asp tagged controls. Change controls from `<button>` to `<asp:Button>`, etc. to solve this.

Answer (score -1):

I think I found a cleaner solution to the problem. I set the onbeforeunload to null inside the callback, and reset it prior to exit:

```
...
window.onbeforeunload=confirmExit;

function confirmExit(){
    window.onbeforeunload=null;
    event.returnValue="You have not saved your document yet.";
    window.onbeforeunload=confirmExit;
}
```