# IE 11 beforeunload twice

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, onbeforeunload

To prevent users leaving a form I make use of the event beforeunload:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', exit_page);
```

For Firefox and Chrome this method is working fine but for Internet Explorer the beforeunload function is called twice.

Therefore I implemented the trick of remembering that the event is called and set a timeout function. Like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967934/ie9-onbeforeunload-called-twice-when-window-location-changed-in-button-event).

For a couple of years this solution worked fine. But now I notice that this trick is not working for IE11. When the exit_page function is called for the second time and doesn't return a String, IE11 will not show a pop up message to prevent leaving the page but will just continue. Also for the cases returning (and set the (e || window.event).returnValue) null, false, will either do the same or show the pop up message for the second time (with false as message for example.)

If the user wants to leave the page, the dialog only shows ones and then  the page redirects.

I could not find a working solution for IE11 to prevent the beforeunload dialog for the second time. Is there a solution to fix this problem?

Comment: `e.returnValue` is not implemented in jQuery, just return the string instead. Notice, that you don't have to check, if the `event` argument is there, it is passed always, when working with jQuery.