# beforeunload event fires twice in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [onbeforeunload Message Appears Twice (Internet Explorer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917074/onbeforeunload-message-appears-twice-internet-explorer)

I'm facing the issue of firing the `beforeunload` event twice on IE. The code below works on other browsers:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
    evt.stopPropagation();

    if (isDirty) {
        isDirty = false;
        return dirtyMsg;
    }
};
```

I've seen many other posts, but not were solved.