# Javascript- Stay on the current page not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

I want to show the confirmation message when user navigate to another page.

But I am facing a problem, if user select "Stay On the Current Page", the browser is taking user to another page.

Please see my code below.

```
var onBeforeUnloadFired = false;

   window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    if ($("#aspnetForm").serialize() != form_original_data){
        if(!onBeforeUnloadFired){
            onBeforeUnloadFired = true;
            event.returnValue =  "No changes have been saved. Are you sure you wish to cancel?";              
        }
        window.setTimeout("ResetOnBeforeUnloadFired()", 0);
    }
};

function ResetOnBeforeUnloadFired() {
    onBeforeUnloadFired = false;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: For starters, your setTimeout method has bad syntax.  I would recommend wrapping this up in a function, e.g. window.setTimeout(function() { ... }, 0).   But there may be further issues still

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about this variables going up and down. I'd do:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    if ($("#aspnetForm").serialize() != form_original_data){        
        return "No changes have been saved. Are you sure you wish to cancel?;"                   
    }
}
```

Comment: If I don't use the variables then the onbeforeunload method is called twice.

Answer (score 0):

Which browser are you using? If it is not IE use

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {

});
```

Comment: I am facing the problem in IE and chrome.

Comment: then you have semantical error. what is your code doing when user selects to stay on the current page?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I found it was related to this issue:

[onbeforeunload Message Appears Twice (Internet Explorer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917074/onbeforeunload-message-appears-twice-internet-explorer)

Basically using the setTimeout local variable trick to temporarily disable the handler was masking the underlying problem of using window.location = "some url" in my code instead of window.location.href = "some location".

Once I changed

```
window.location = "..."
```

to

```
window.location.href = "..."
```

the "Stay on the current page" not working issue disappeared.